# How do I get CreateUsingInMemory() to work with MassTransit?

Tags: c#, masstransit

Here's my entire code.  I think the test should pass, but it fails.  I've (unsuccessfully) tried using some of the overloads to `Consumer`.

```
using MassTransit;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MassTransitTests
{
    public class Message
    {
    }

    public class MessageConsumer : IConsumer<Message>
    {
        public static int ConsumedCount
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Message> context)
        {
            ConsumedCount++;
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class MassTransitTest
    {
        [Test]
        public async Task BasicTestAsync()
        {
            // Arrange
            var control = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory(configure =>
            {
                configure.ReceiveEndpoint("myQueue", endpoint =>
                {
                    endpoint.Consumer<MessageConsumer>();
                });
            });

            // Act
            using (var handle = control.Start())
            {
                await control.Publish(new Message());
                await control.Publish(new Message());
            }

            // Assert
            Assert.That(MessageConsumer.ConsumedCount, Is.EqualTo(2));
        }
    }
}
```

Their [documentation](http://masstransit.readthedocs.org/en/master/configuration/transports/in_memory.html?highlight=inmemory) shows this, which is what I'm doing:

```
var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory(cfg =>
{
    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("queue_name", ep =>
    {
       //configure the endpoint
    })
});
```

**What am I doing wrong/what I do need to change in my Arrange/Act to get my Assert to work?**

Comment: You could also use the ```MassTransit.TestFramework``` with NUnit, and use the ```InMemoryTestFixture``` to setup your test for you. Look at https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit.Tests/MultiTestConsumer_Specs.cs#L29 for an example, which also uses the ```MultiTestConsumer``` to test message consumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging through their tests, I found what I was missing:

[1] You need* to `await` `BusHandle.Ready`, which I wasn't doing. *(*The test works without this - at least the first time I ran it, but that may just be a race condition working in my favor....)*

[2] The calls to `Publish` apparently complete whenever the bus has received the message I'm guessing - not when the handlers/consumers of the message have completed their work.  Therefore you need to notify the calling code that the handlers have finished if that's what you're testing.  Here's one way to do this - use `TaskCompletionSource<T>` (similar to what I found in their codebase).  Obviously I may not have been perfect in my thread-safety and my `lock` usage is a bit sledge-hammer-esque, but this illustrates the point:

```
using MassTransit;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MassTransitTests
{
    public class Message
    {
    }

    public class MessageConsumer : IConsumer<Message>
    {        
        public static int TargetConsumedCount
        {
            get { return _targetConsumedCount; }
            set
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    _targetConsumedCount = value;
                    CheckTargetReached();
                }
            }
        }

        private static void CheckTargetReached()
        {
            if (_consumedCount >= TargetConsumedCount)
            {
                _targetReached.SetResult(true);
            }
        }

        public static Task<bool> TargetReached { get; private set; }

        private static int _consumedCount;
        private static int _targetConsumedCount;
        private static TaskCompletionSource<bool> _targetReached;
        private static object _lock;

        static MessageConsumer()
        {
            _lock = new object();
            _targetReached = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            TargetReached = _targetReached.Task;
        }

        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Message> context)
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                _consumedCount++;
                CheckTargetReached();
            }
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class MassTransitTest
    {
        [Test]
        public async Task BasicTestAsync()
        {
            // Arrange
            var control = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory(configure =>
            {
                configure.ReceiveEndpoint("myQueue", endpoint =>
                {
                    endpoint.Consumer<MessageConsumer>();
                });
            });

            using (var handle = control.Start())
            {
                await handle.Ready; // [1]

                // Act
                await control.Publish(new Message());
                await control.Publish(new Message());

                // Assert
                MessageConsumer.TargetConsumedCount = 2;
                await MessageConsumer.TargetReached; // [2]
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: #2 is correct; publish finishes when the message is delivered -- not when the message has been consumed.